# How to use time function and pass the time through named pipe

Tags: c

I am trying to create client server communication through named pipe. From my client I want to send current time. I am trying to use `time()` function but the time won't appear on my server side terminal. I just see provided text. What am I doing wrong?

server

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {

    char *pathname = "/tmp/myfifo";
    int make_fifo = mkfifo(pathname, 0666);
    
    char str[80];
    for(;;){
        int opn = open(pathname, O_RDONLY);
        read(opn, str, sizeof(str));
        close(opn);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

client

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    char *pathname = "/tmp/myfifo";
    time_t current_time = time(0);
    char str[80];
    
    int fd = open(pathname, O_WRONLY);
    fgets(str, 80, stdin);  
    write(fd, str, sizeof(str));
    write(fd, (void*) current_time, sizeof(current_time));

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: should be &current_time

Comment: Looks like, o the server side, you're trying to read the time data using `read(opn, str, sizeof(str));`.  But you're not doing anything with it, which may explain why you're not seeing anything.

Comment: That said, you're writing the time as a binary int (probably 4 bytes).  So you'll have to take that into account when reading and printing it on the server side.

Comment: You're ignoring the return values of `read()` and `write()` so you don't know how much data was actually read/written by those calls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

1. client: Not passing the address of `current_time`.<sup>*1</sup>

   ```
   // write(fd, (void*) current_time, sizeof(current_time)); 
   write(fd, &current_time, sizeof(current_time));  // Add &
   ```
2. server: not reading the time.
3. Ignoring return values of `read()/write()`.

---

<sup>*1</sup>  Avoid casting like `(void*) current_time`.  Casting tends to hide errors.